# Existence $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ln(n)-k \in \left] a,b \right[$ if $ ln(N)-k\leq a$ under some conditions.

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms

**Context and assumption**s : In an exercice , i consider a couple of  reals **(a,b)** such that $a\neq b$, and $a\leq b$.
we choose these two reals to be such as $\left]a,b \right[\subset \left[0,1\right]$

In a first time , we say that there exists an integer $N$ such that for each $n\geq N$, $\vert ln(n+1)-ln(n)\vert < b-a$

Let's then fix this integer $N$ (I mean , it exists , and let's call it $N$)

we then consider $k$ , an integer such as $ln(N)-k \leq a$

**Question : Show that there exists an integer $n \geq N+1$ such that  $ln(n)-k \in \left] a,b \right[$.**

*what i have tried :* I thought using the absolute value to create inequality was the obvious way of unwinding the problem , more precisely i tried to manipulate this inequality :
$$a-b\leq ln(N+1)-ln(N) \leq b-a $$
I tried adding $k$ , using it's properties , but i can't solve it properly..

Also , i'm conscious the title for the question is a bit "wide" in sense , so feel free to change it if you have a better idea.